# How to set multiple settings in sbt console?

Tags: scala, sbt

I know I can use `set` to set a setting, but is there a way to add a bunch of settings from the sbt console?

Comment: What do you mean by "bunch" of settings? A `Seq[Setting]`? In that case you can also use `set`: it will be happy to accept a `Seq`.

Comment: @sjrd wow, excellent. So simple I didn't think of it. Thanks! Make that the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `set` as well with a `Seq[Setting[_]]`. `set` accepts either a single `Setting[_]` or a `Seq[Setting[_]]`.

```
> show name
[info] set-seq
> show version
[info] 1.0
> set Seq(name := "abc", version := "2.0")
[info] Defining *:name, *:version
[info] The new values will be used by *:description, *:isSnapshot and 8 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to abc (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/set-seq/)
> show name
[info] abc
> show version
[info] 2.0
```

This is similar to `build.sbt` files, in which separate lines can be either `Setting[_]` or a `Seq[Setting[_]]`.